# How to join two different Data extension with same Subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i am very new in SFMC and i try to build email for my company,which has personalized button for each costumer. We have two DE's and DE1 has subscriber-key and register rows.
DE2 has subscriber-key and url rows. I want to build a personalized link for button. If an user from DE1 register "true" is then user must get the url from DE2.But subscriber-key must match with two DE's.I wrote some ampscript code but i have no idea how to rest.Thanks alot for helping.

```
%%[
SET @register = Lookup("DE1","subscriber-key""register","true")
SET @url = Lookup("DE2","subscriber-key","url")

IF @register = @url THEN
 SET @output = 

]%%
%%=v(@output)=%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should go something like this:

```
%%[
set @subscriberkey = AttributeValue("subscriber-key")
set @registered = Lookup("DE1","register","subscriber-key",@subscriberkey)
set @url = Lookup("DE2","url","subscriber-key",@subscriberkey)

if @registered == "true" then
]%%
<a href="%%=v(@url)=%%">click here</a>
%%[
endif
]%%
```

This is based on the assumption that in both DEs you have a subscriber key field called `subscriber-key`. If field names are different, please let me know and I will adjust the anwser.

More on using the Lookup function and conditional statements:

- https://ampscript.guide/lookup/
- https://ampscript.guide/statements/

Comment: Thanks alot for your response and yes it solved my problem :)

Comment: Great to hear, please remember to accept the answer by ticking the check mark :-)

Comment: i have done :) would you be able to help me about other issue with ssjs ? i am trying to impliment friendlycapcha in to formulars but these are connected to cloudpage ??

Comment: Please post a new question and I am sure someone will pick it up :-)